# Trigram probability in an enormous text file

Tags: php, python, nlp, counting

I have a large Bengali monolingual corpus which consists of over 100 million Bengali sentences. The corpus is in .txt format and the file size is 1.8 GB. 
Now, in order to build a Bengali Grammar checker, I need to use this enormous corpus to calculate Trigram language probability. However, this seems to take an enormous amount of time to find Trigram probability in such a large file. Please suggest how to solve this issue and which techniques should I use in this case. Should I use php or python for this? I have sufficient knowledge in both. TIA

Comment: I would suggest "divide and conquer". Split your file and perform simultaneous processes.

Comment: Dont do this in php for your own sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you already *know* that it will be challenging to get this working, why make your life hard and use Python or even worse, PHP?

This is a fairly straightforward task: counting.

That *really* is something that you can implement in a more *memory efficient* and faster language like C, if you need it to be fast. For example, an integer (and you will need many) in C is 4 bytes, in Python you need 12, and most likely these will be stored in a different memory location, so you have another 8 just to reference where the integer is. A pure python approach will easily need 3x-4x as much memory as a C version. All these memory indirections also reduce your performance.

You can then still work with Python for the later steps.